# ObservableList replacement in Bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx, bloc, state-management

I have used mobx for state management. And the good thing about the mobx is that you can observe the variable and tie it to the UI so that when a variable changes the UI updates.

I have been trying out the bloc for state management. the bloc is the map between the events to the states which makes it easier to separate the UI from the logic.

But what the appropriate replacement of the `observableList` from the mobx in the bloc?
How to handle the updating list properly in the bloc, it seems if anything updates in the list then just pass the entire updated list again.

in mobx we have to declare the list as `ObservableList` and attach it to the UI and as the list gets updated the UI gets updated.